# Android Application force closing:'com.google.android.gsf' not found

Tags: android, reporting-services, google-play, google-cloud-messaging, versions

I am creating an android application in which I would like to navigate to some screens using `Intent`.

Everything works well in Android Kitkat(4.4) and lower versions. But it comes to Android Lolipop(5.0), the application closing by itself.

I'm facing an error which shows: Device doesnot contain 'com.google.android.gsf' package.But app is installed perfectly but while navigating to some screens only ,the app is forcibly closing.

#### screenshot of logcat at runtime.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: show some code and stack trace after error

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).